# Setting the text color based on state of a Custom Tab View

Tags: android

I was able to implement a custom Tab view with assistance of a question on StackOverflow. So i have a custom tab view as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/TabLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" android:padding="5dip">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/TabImageView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/TabTextView" android:text="Text" android:paddingTop="5dip"        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I inflate it as follows

```
MainActivity.addTab(this, this.mTabHost,     this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(prepareTabView("Smoker",     R.drawable.ic_smoker)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", MainFragment.class, args)));
```

Function looks as follows

```
private View prepareTabView(String text, int resId) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.TabImageView);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TabTextView);
    iv.setImageResource(resId);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

I have a style defined for the Drawable resource as follows

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_selected="true"
           android:state_pressed="false"
           android:drawable="@drawable/ic_smoker_green" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_smoker_red" />
    </selector>`

My question is how do i get the text color to change based on the state of the Tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set in your main xml textview as

```
android:textColor="@drawable/text_col"
```

and in drawable create another file say text_col.xml, i hope this will do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ff7BCFFC" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff7BCFFC" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff7BCFFC" />

<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@drawable/box_col" ></item>
<item android:color="#ffffffff" />
```